# AzureAD GraphAPI: memberOf API response has null group displayName if I log in on a mobile device

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Part of our login code is...

1. Redirect the user to a **[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenat-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenat-id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)** URL
2. Once the user is redirected back to our site, use the returned **code** value to get an **access token**
3. Use this **access token** to get a list of the Azure AD groups that the user belongs to using the **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf** API

This works fine on desktop browsers, but if I do the same process on a mobile browser (I am testing with Chrome on a modern Android phone), the memberOf API response has null values for the group displayName values. Some other values are also null

The login.microsoftonline.com URLs which we are redirecting the users to are the same for desktop and mobile browsers

Here's a screenshot of the differences in the API responses

[image]

Is this a known issue? Is there anything extra which needs to be done when logging in on a mobile browser?